# How to execute pressButton method using appium and robot framework for iOS 17

Tags: ios, robotframework, mobile-development, appium-ios

Im using "Execute Script" keyword to run this method:  mobile: pressButton{name: "home"} on a real device (iPhone 12, iOS 17.2.1) connected to a MacMini M2 (Sonoma 14.1.1).

```
Execute Script    mobile: pressButton{name: "home"}
```

Webdriver throws an exception with this message: *Method is not implemented.*

Is there something wrong with the syntax or something else?

Appium version: 2.0.1,
robotframework-appiumlibrary: 1.5.0.7,
Python version: 2.7.14

I want to press Home button on a real iPhone device.